# Custom keyboard shortcut for fill colour

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create my own keyboard shortcuts that change the fill colour of a selected cell.

I'm trying to make it so I can type "Control-shift-r" and get the cell to turn red, and then "Control-shift-b" for blue and "Control-shift-g" for green.

In "ThisWorsheet" I have:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set AppEvents = Application
        Application.OnKey "^+r", "Fill_Red"
        Application.OnKey "^+b", "Fill_Blue"
        Application.OnKey "^+g", "Fill_Green"
End Sub
```

In Module1 I have:

```
Sub Fill_Red()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub

Sub Fill_Blue()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End Sub

Sub Fill_Green()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your issue? Is `ThisWorsheet` a typo?

Comment: Oh sorry - my issue is just that it doesn't work. What's weird is that when I click run macro it works just fine. It just doesn't respond to the keystroke combination.

Comment: If `Workbook_Open` is in the module `ThisWorkbook`, you need to close and reopen the Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply assign keystrokes in Excel to call the macros:
On the Macro-Menu (Either via Ribbon [Developer] or [View]), Select the macro (eg `Fill_Blue`), Click the [Options] Button and assign the keystroke you want. Be careful not to interfere with keyboard shortcuts defined by Excel (uppercase characters are save).

[image]

If you want that those macros (and keyboard shortcuts) work on every workbook, put the code into your `Personal` workbook (if you don't have a `Personal` workbook, simply start to record a macro and choose "Personal Macro Workbook" as location to store it, Excel will create it for you).

Note that `Selection` can be anything. To avoid that you get a runtime error when something is selected that can't be colored, put a `On Error Resume Next` statement before you assign the color:

```
Sub Fill_Red()
    setcolor RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub

Sub Fill_Blue()
    setcolor RGB(0, 0, 255)
End Sub

Sub Fill_Green()
    setcolor RGB(0, 255, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub setcolor(color As Long)
    On Error Resume Next    ' In case Selection is not valid
    Selection.Interior.color = color
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

To make this run you have to first run the worksheet macro once and after that only short keys will work.

However, if you want to make it run without running any macro prior, you need to change the things as i circled in below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcTBF.png)